Schema-validation: missing column [dtype]
I have a app with postgres,liquidbase, on kotlin.
I have this entity
@Table(name = "events")
@Entity
open class AbstractEvent(
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)
    @Column(name = "aggregateId", nullable = true)
    open var aggregateId: UUID?,
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "eventType", nullable = false)
    open var eventType: EventType?,
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    @Convert(converter = ObjectConverter::class)
    open var payload: Any?
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    var id: Long? = null

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "creationTimestamp", nullable = false)
    val timestamp: LocalDateTime? = null

}

and this my changeLog for this entity
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: add-events
      author: Dan
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: events
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: aggregate_id
                  type: UUID
              - column:
                  name: event_type
                  type: varchar(200)
              - column:
                  name: payload
                  type: JSON
              - column:
                  name: creationTimestamp
                  type: timestamp
              - column:
                  name: id
                  type: varchar(200)

And when i trying to start app i get error:
Schema-validation: missing column [dtype] in table [events]
But i havent field dtype. What does it mean?
This class have only one child:
@Entity
class CreateWordAndStat(
    override var aggregateId: UUID?,
    override var eventType: EventType?,
    override var payload: Any?
) : AbstractEvent(aggregateId, eventType, payload)

I am trying to restart my DB, and drop all tables(include changes history)
